# Get bearer token and consume token from another API

Tags: java, spring-boot, bearer-token

I have created an API to get bearer token and use the token on the same API as I got the token, here is the controller I have created:

```
@GetMapping("/getNik")
    public String pushToken() {
        //generate token
        String uri = "http://some-url-to-get-token"; 
        String notEncoded ="*****:******";
        String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(notEncoded.getBytes());
        System.out.println("encodeUserPass "+encodedAuth);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.set("client_id", "client_id");
            headers.set("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedAuth);

          
            HttpEntity<String> result = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
            String token = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, result, String.class);
            
            Object obj=JSONValue.parse(token); 
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj; 
            String access_token = (String) jsonObject.get("access_token"); 
            //dapat token
            System.out.println("baru di get "+access_token);
            
            
        //hit get nik
        String urix = "http:/some-url-that-need-otp-to-access"; 
        RestTemplate restTemplatex = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headersx = new HttpHeaders();
        headersx.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headersx.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+access_token);
        System.out.println("initokennya "+access_token);

        HttpEntity<String> resultx = new HttpEntity<String>(headersx);
        System.out.println("sama?"+resultx);
        //fail
        String get = restTemplatex.getForObject(urix ,String.class, resultx);
        
        return get;
    }
```

The problem is when I got the token, I try to hit the API, but I can't use it, error 401 Unauthorized is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
```